# Grouping database data by hour

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that stores the data of every user that visits my site. I use UNIX timestamps to indicate the time of the visit.

I want to get the number of visits for each hour between time x and time y.

Here's what I can think of:

1. Using MySQL grouping:

The problem with this method is that it doesn't address the hours where there were no visits, and I need the data for each and every hour between x and y, not just for the ones that there were visits.

```
// the timestamp for 03/16/2015
$x = 1426489200;
// the timestamp for 04/16/2015
$y = 1429167600;
//Getting the nearest hour
$start = floor($x / 3600) * 3600;
$end = ceil($y / 3600) * 3600;
$Db->query("SELECT ROUND(time/3600) AS timekey, COUNT(*) FROM visits WHERE time>='$start' AND time<='$end' GROUP BY timekey");
```

2. Using PHP

This method should work fine, but I'm worried about the performance, especially if x and y are 1 month apart for example.

```
// the timestamp for 03/16/2015
$x = 1426489200;
// the timestamp for 04/16/2015
$y = 1429167600;
//Getting the nearest hour
$start = floor($x / 3600) * 3600;
$end = ceil($y / 3600) * 3600;
// the number of hours between start and end
$hourCount = ($end - $start) / 3600;
for ($i = 0; $i < $hourCount; $i++) {
    $hourStart = $start + $i * 3600;
    $hourEnd = $hourStart + 3599;
    $query = $Db->query("SELECT time FROM visits WHERE time>='$hourStart' AND time<='$hourEnd'");
    $visitCount = $query->num_rows;
}
```

Comment: A good way to start would be analyzing the query using `explain select..` , this would give you an idea about the query health. The 2nd part is its always better to have one query than multiple since in the later case it will need to send and receive data across network multiple time.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you want to accomplish:

```
SELECT DAY(time), HOUR(time), * FROM visits
GROUP BY DAY(time), HOUR(time)
```

Using [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) link, I'm sure you will find out how to solve your problem!
(Just don't use the PHP method, only one query should be sufficient.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is kind of what I want to accomplish, but there's a problem with this method. It returns all hours when there were visitors, but I want it to return all hours, meaning that if there were no visitors for a particular hour, I should get 0.

Comment: @Jeff -- LEFT JOIN to a dummy table containing all the hours!

Comment: I see what you need, but couldn't you fix this in the application code?

Comment: marijnz0r, unfortunately, I can't fix it in the application code. James, this looks like the solution I am looking for. Thanks!